Perpendicular distance between two points on different curves
I have two curves, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+$sin$x$. Their graphs would look like: 
Then if I zoom in at $x=3π/2$,
Let BC be a perpendicular from B:$(3π/2,3.71)$ lying on $g(x)$ to the line $f(x)$.
I know AB=1 and $\angle{ABC}=π/4$.
How do I find the exact value, or good approximation of length BC? 
I have an understanding of differential calculus (somewhat) and high school algebra, as well as trigonometry and Euclidean geometry.

Another way to interpret your question is to find the length of perpendicular from $B\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}-1\right)$ to the line $y=x$.

There's a formula for this. The perpendicular distance from a point $X(a,b)$ to a line $px+qy+r=0$ is $$\frac{|pa+qb+r|}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$$
Using this formula in your question, immediately gives the result as $$\boxed{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}$$

Triangle $ABC$ is right angled at $C$ so $\cosπ/4 = 1/2^{1/2} = BC/AB $
$AB=1$, So $BC = 1/2^{1/2}$

You know the slope, call it $m$, of $AC$. The slope of the perpendicular would be $-1/m$. Now you have a point on the perpendicular (namely $B$) and the slope of the perpendicular. So you have the equation for the perpendicular. So set the formulas for the two lines equal and solve for the $x$-coordinate of $B$, which you can plug into either formula to get $B$’s $y$-coordinate. Then use the distance formula.
It’s perpendicular to $AC$. Will it also be perpendicular to the other curve’s tangent at $B$? I ask because of the way you worded your post’s title.

You're right, the "perpendicular" is redundant. I was merely asking the distance between points on the two curves.
